# What happens to Rebus failed messages

Tags: c#, rebus

In older versions of Rebus you could control the error queue.  But now you only have a "inputQueue" in the azure servicebus extender.  How can I control the error queue?

```
Bus = Configure.With(_adapter)
            .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(ConnectionString, inputQueue /*, errorQueue */))
            .Start();
```

UPDATE: they end up in the "error" queue.  I have now messages from different sources in the same (error)queue.  So, the question became, can rebus filter out messages where the input queue matches the custom property `rbs2-source-queue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error queue is still configurable!

You made me realize that this was not something that I had mentioned on the wiki though, [so I just went and added it :)](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling#configuring-which-error-queue-to-use)

The solution to configuring which error queue to use is pretty simple - check this out:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .Options(b => b.SimpleRetryStrategy(errorQueueAddress: "somewhere_else"))
    .(...)
```

As you have correctly discovered, the `rbs2-source-queue` header reveals which input queue the message failed too many times in, and therefore it can be used for filtering the failed messages later on. There's no way, though, to only receive those messages that have a specific value in that header.

Comment: Is the dead letter queue used by default on the azure servicebus implementation?

Comment: Yes - but I am thinking about having the Azure Service Bus transport disable Rebus' built-in deadlettering, passing that responsibility to Azure Service Bus... it will probably work like that in a future release of Rebus. If you have any feedback or input regarding this decision, please let me know :)

Comment: I like the idea of a separation between - we never touched this and it went on timeout - and on the other hand - something bad happened -.  But maybe we should not start this discussion here...